# Modificar chave estrangeira para auto-increment

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com duas tabelas no meu banco

```
membro, membro_grupo, grupo
```

A tabela `grupo` tem uma coluna chamada `id_grupo` que é chave primária nessa tabela. A tabela `membro` tem uma coluna chamada `id_membro` que também é chave primária. A tabela `membro_grupo` tem duas chaves estrangeiras, uma chamada `id_grupo` e outra chamada `id_membro` insira o código aqui, que fazem associação com as tabelas anteriores. Só que cometi um pequeno erro na hora que criei essas tabelas. Esqueci de colocar o `id_grupo` da tabela `grupo` como **auto-increment**, e agora não consigo modificar. Como consigo fazer essa troca?

Answer (score 3):

Pode executar isso diretamente na query sql:

ALTER TABLE **nome_da_tabela** MODIFY COLUMN **nome_da_coluna** INT(6) auto_increment

Obviamente, precisa trocar os nomes em negrito.

O trecho `INT(6)`, troque o número 6 pela quantidade que deseja. Representa a quantidade de dígitos.

obs: Se já existir dados nessa tabela, deve checar se os IDs já gerados são do mesmo tipo `INT`.

## Definindo valor inicial do auto incremento

Caso queira definir um valor inicial específico para o auto incremento, execute a query:

```
ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```

Troque o número pelo valor que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

`ALTER TABLE grupo MODIFY id_grupo INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: mas não tem que dar LOCK antes? Eu tentei usar com LOCK mas deu errado

Comment: Opá, então tente sem `LOCK` agora.

Comment: está dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Põe aí na sua pergunta o erro que dá.